# Rewriting a nonlinear transformation in multiple dimensions

Tags: real-analysis, transformation, nonlinear-analysis

Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $n>0$. Suppose we have an arbitrary nonlinear mapping $T(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, that basically performs a nonlinear coordinate transformation for which we assume that $\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}$ has full rank for all $x$ (so it is a 'valid' transformation, so to speak). My question is; Does there always exists a $Q:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, such that for all $x,y$
$$T(x)-T(y)=Q(x,y)(x-y).$$
And if not, what are the conditions on $T$, such that the above holds?

For $n=1$, it is quite easy, i.e. $Q(x,y)=\frac{T(x)-T(y)}{x-y}$, but for higher dimensions, this is a bit more tricky...

Comment: The problem I run into is that $vv^T$ is only full rank when $n=1$

Comment: @NinadMunshi, could you elaborate on what you mean? I'm not sure if I understand correctly. For example, what is $v$ in your case?

Comment: I guess you want to assume some sort of regularity for $Q$?  Otherwise the existence of such a $Q$ is trivial, since a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be sent to any other vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a linear map.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, I want $Q$ to be continuous over $x$ and $y$, otherwise it would be indeed trivial by choosing some linear map for any $x,y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if $T:\mathbb{U}\rightarrow R^n$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{U}$ and $\mathbb{U}$ is open, it holds that

$$ T(x)-T(y)= \underbrace{\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\partial T}{\partial x}(y+t(x-y))\,d t\right)}_{Q(x,y)}(x-y)$$
for $x,y\in\mathbb{U}$, see Lemma 1 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for!